# Checking a string if it is a valid palindrome or not using python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, palindrome

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        string=''
        ss=s.lower()
        
        for x in ss:
            if x.isalnum():
                string.join(x)
        bol= string == string[::-1]
                
        return bol
```

```
str_1="A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"  
str_2="race a car"
```

For str_1 the code is working properly (output is TRUE) but for str_2 also the output is TRUE but it is not a palindrome.
I couldn't understand whats the error in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not saving every time that you are joining the string.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        string=''
        ss=s.lower()
        
        for x in ss:
            if x.isalnum():
                string += ''.join(x) # Remember to save the new added character
        bol= string == string[::-1]
                
        return bol
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        string=""
        ss=s.lower()
        
        string = ''.join(x for x in ss if x.isalnum())    
        
        bol= string == string[::-1]
                
        return bol
```

output:

```
#for str_1
True
# for str_2
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a string, write a python function to check if it is palindrome or not. A string is said to be palindrome if the reverse of the string is the same as string. For example, “radar” is a palindrome, but “radix” is not a palindrome.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]    
 
# Driver code
s = "hello"
ans = isPalindrome(s)
 
if ans:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problem with this easy code;

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str):
        s = s.lower()
        s = "".join(filter(str.isalnum, s))
        if s == s[::-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Test;

```
s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"

sol = Solution()
print(sol.isPalindrome(s=s))
```

Output: True